# Android adapter best practice when using attributes from activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My Adapter requires a context in order to apply resources to views, therefore when instantiating it, I might do the following within my Activity:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

As my adapter also needs data from an activity, I might do this:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myItemsArrayList,this);
```

As my adapter might also need to know which items in the ArrayList are selected, I might pass it that list too:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myArrayItemsList,mySelectedItemsArrayList,this);
```

And as there may be other states (e.g. whether to display photos in a list of people, the constructor call is starting to get quite lengthy:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myArrayItemsList,mySelectedItemsArrayList,myPreference1,myPreference2,this);
```

Given that the only place this adapter will be used is from a particular activity, how bad would it be to just make those attributes in the activity public, so that I can access them via the activity that has been passed (e.g `myActivity.myArrayItemsList`)?

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that the only place this adapter will be used is from a particular activity, how bad would it be to just make those attributes in the activity public, so that I can access them via the activity that has been passed (e.g myActivity.myArrayItemsList)?

That's a bad code and bad behavior. You're code will be tightly coupled. And usually, you will *borrow* the same behavior to your next project.

Instead of passing each state to your constructor, you can simplify it by passing a State object to your adapter. Create the State class something like this:

```
public class State {
   List<String> selectedItems;
   boolean displayPeople;
}
```

then you can create a simple constructor like this:

```
State state = new State();
state.selectedItems = mSelectedItems;
state.displayPeople = true;

myAdapter = new MyAdapter(items, state, this);
```

So, whenever you need to update a new state, you just need to add it the State class and update the Adapter according to it.

Comment: Good point about the code being tightly coupled, but really there's no escaping that in this specific instance, so isn't a big concern here. The suggestion of using a State class will make things prettier, but there is no other benefit other than that, is there? It might be easier to stick with just listing the attributes in the constructor.

Comment: The main benefit is you don't need to keep remembering the parameter position. Sometimes you'll have to rechecked if you have passed the correct parameters when some of the parameters are using a same variable type. You avoided a context switching and gaining more times to code.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using the **Item** object for **myArrayItemsList**.

So your list should look like this:

```
 ArrayList<Item> myArrayItemsList = new ArrayList();
```

and then you want to add the selected items in the list you could add a boolean to the **Item** object ex:

```
public class Item {
private String itemName;
private boolean selected = false;

public Item(){}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName= itemName;
}

public boolean isSelected () {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected= selected;
}
```

}

and just check your item list in the adapter if the item is selected.

So your adapter would only pass two parameters:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myArrayItemsList, this);
```

But then again you want to pass only one parameter in adapter, you can set your ArrayList to static

```
public static ArrayList<Item> myArrayItemsList = new ArrayList();
```

and pass only this your adapter

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

used the static ArrayList in your adapter but it is not advisable using those static data because the data could be Garbage Collected in the memory.

Comment: Thanks MJ, I had considered this approach too, but ultimately it's not perfect for what I'm looking for. I was most interested to hear how strongly the community felt about making member variables (i.e. the array list) public, so that an associated adapter to use them.

Comment: @Ben at first I'm also confused about things like this, I get your point like just passing the Context of the activity and just get the public variable from that activity but in android architecture, you should always arrange your code to be independent as much as possible, because when that activity is killed your variable is also cleared along with it and there might be another activity using it and the variable is already cleared and could lead to a buggy application.